# Determining if a list numbers are sequential

Tags: java, oop

I'm working in Java.  I have an unordered list of 5 numbers ranging from 0-100 with no repeats.  I'd like to detect if 3 of the numbers are sequential with no gap.

Examples:

```
[9,12,13,11,10] true
[17,1,2,3,5] true
[19,22,23,27,55] false
```

As for what I've tried, nothing yet.  If I were to write it now, I would probably go with the most naive approach of ordering the numbers, then iteratively checking if a sequence exists.

Comment: I don't get it - how is the first sequence `true`?

Comment: I think the question is, are there 3 numbers which could be arranged to be sequential with no gap.

Comment: @Pace: Ah yes, that must be it.

Comment: The first one is this one http://oeis.org/A007305

Comment: doesnt look like apache.commons :D suggestion: just implement your algorithm as you mentioned. sort and go through, setting a flag if 3 inkrmentals are detected

Comment: One question regarding your requirements, does it have to be exactly *3 elements* or *3 or more elements*?

Comment: Three or more.  This is what makes the first sequence `true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int sequenceMin(int[] set) {
    int[] arr = Arrays.copy(set);
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 3 + 1; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] == arr[i + 2] - 2) {
            return arr[i];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This sorts the array and looks for the desired sequence using the if-statement above, returning the first value.

---

***Without sorting:***

(@Pace mentioned the wish for non-sorting.) A limited range can use an efficient "boolean array", BitSet. The iteration with `nextSetBit` is fast.

```
    int[] arr = {9,12,13,11,10};
    BitSet numbers = new BitSet(101);
    for (int no : arr) {
        numbers.set(no);
    }
    int sequenceCount = 0;
    int last = -10;
    for (int i = numbers.nextSetBit(0); i >= 0; i = numbers.nextSetBit(i+1)) {
        if (sequenceCount == 0 || i - last > 1) {
            sequenceCount = 1;
        } else {
            sequenceCount++;
            if (sequenceCount >= 3) {
                System.out.println("Sequence start: " + (last - 1));
                break;
            }
        }
        last = i;
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
```

Comment: The OP already said he had a solution using a sort but was looking for a solution not using a sort.

Answer (score 3):

Very naive (but faster) algorithm : (your array is input[], assuming it only contains 0-100 numbers as you said)

```
int[] nums=new int[101];
for(i=0;i<N;i++) 
   {
   int a=input[i];
   nums[a]++;
   if (a>0) { nums[a-1]++; }
   if (a<100) { nums[a+1]++; }
   }
```

Then look if there is an element of nums[]==3.

Could be faster with some HashMap instead of the array (and removes the 0-100 limitation)

---

Edit : Alas, this does NOT work if two numbers could be equal in the initial sequence

Comment: Requires you to loop through an array of 100 size.

Comment: If anyone is wondering why this isn't the selected answer, I tested and chose the fastest answer.  I appreciate the answer though.

Answer (score 3):

This code seems to be implementing your requirements:

```
public class OrderdedList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(orderedWithNoGap(Arrays.asList(9, 12, 13, 11, 10))); // true
        System.out.println(orderedWithNoGap(Arrays.asList(17,1,2,3,5))); // true
        System.out.println(orderedWithNoGap(Arrays.asList(19,22,23,27,55))); // false
    }

    private static boolean orderedWithNoGap(List<Integer> list) {       
        Collections.sort(list);
        Integer prev = null;
        int seq = 0;
        for(Integer i : list) {
            if(prev != null && prev+1 == i)
                seq = seq == 0 ? 2 : seq+1;
            prev = i;
        }
        return seq >= 3;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you run this? `Arrays.asList()` returns an immutable `List`

Comment: @LukasEder Yes, I did. `public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) { return new ArrayList<T>(a); }`

Comment: @LukasEder It returns a fixed-sized `List` which is _not_ `java.util.ArrayList`. You can't `add()` to it and you can't `remove()` from it, but you can call `set()`, so in-place mutations are ok.

Comment: That's not a `java.util.ArrayList`, it's a `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`. But I was wrong, it isn't immutable. It's just a fixed-size list. Wow, learned something today! (after all these years...)

Comment: Requires a sort which the OP seemed to imply he did not want.

Comment: *If I were to write it now, I would probably go with the most naive approach of ordering the numbers...*, sometimes the simplest solutions are the best :)

Comment: Indeed, I'm not opposed to sorting _if_ it's the most efficient solution; however, intuitively I suspect it is not.  In this case there are definitely faster solutions (although the answer is obviously appreciated).

Answer (score 1):

Allocate an array of size 100:

```
private static final int MAX_VALUE = 100;

public boolean hasSequence(int [] values) {
  int [] bigArray = new int[MAX_VALUE];

  for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    bigArray[values[i]] = 1;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    index = values[i];
    if(index == 0 || index == MAX_VALUE-1) {
      continue;
    }
    if(bigArray[index-1] == 1 && bigArray[index+1] == 1) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: No, it's readable pseudocode that happens to look like another language I can think of.  It's also the only approach so far that is O(# of items in the list) and would work even if there were duplicates.

Comment: I went ahead and replaced it with a Java form and did away with the small array.

Comment: This solution will throw an index out of bounds exception in the second loop.  Also, shouldn't the second loop loop through the ints IN values, not the ints between 0 and its size?

Comment: I believe that line 7 should read `if(bigArray[values[i]-1] == 1 && bigArray[values[i]+1] == 1)`  but before that, one should check to make sure values[i] != 0.  If this answer is edited to fix this problem, it will be the accepted answer as I believe it is the fastest while also being very clear.

Comment: @roundar Thanks, cleaned that up.  There is no real need to check that values[index] != 0 though.

Comment: If index = 0 or index = bigArray.length - 1, then this will throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks, added that constraint.

Comment: Thank you, this is the fastest solution.

Answer (score 1):

**General Algorithm steps.**

```
Step 1. Sort the array.
Step 2. There are only 3 possible groups of 3 (next to each other) in an array of length five.
indexes 0,1,2 - 1,2,3 - 2,3,4.
Step 3. Check these 3 combinations to see if the next index is 1 more than the current index.
```

Answer (score 0):

As OP pointed out in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235719/determining-if-a-list-numbers-are-sequential/17236320#comment24974196_17235719), he want to check if list contains 3 or more sequential numbers

```
public class WarRoom {

    static final int seqCount = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>((Arrays.asList(9, 11, 123, 511, 10)));
        for (int i : list) {
            if (seqNumbers(list, i, 0) >= seqCount) {
                System.out.println("Lucky Numbers : " + (i++) + "," + (i++) + "," + i);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int seqNumbers(List<Integer> list, int number, int count) {
        if (list.contains(number)) {
            return seqNumbers(list, number + 1, count + 1);
        }
        else {
            return count;
        }
    }
}
```

Its not one of the most efficient solution but I love recursion!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't test this, but for small memory footprint you could use a BitSet

```
private static boolean consecutive(int[] input) {
    BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(100);
    for (int num : input) {
        bitSet.set(num);
    }

    bitSet.and(bitSet.get(1, bitSet.length())); // AND shift left by 1 bit
    bitSet.and(bitSet.get(1, bitSet.length())); // AND shift left by 1 bit

    return !bitSet.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: This answer uses BitSet with bit shift to find consecutive bits in a set