# Detecting missing records on numbered table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a database which stores messages. There is a "count" column, so first message has count 1, second message count 2 etc.

Now I am looking for a way to detect if a message is missing, example: "select count from message" returns 1,2,4 instead of 1,2,3,4.

I use hibernate on the backend. So a solution in Java is welcome too.

Thanks.

Comment: If an in-code solution works, you can just [Determine if a list of numbers are sequential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235719/determining-if-a-list-numbers-are-sequential)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try comparing the row count and max value in 'count' column

```
  SELECT ( count(*) != max(count) ) AS MISSING_MESSAGE FROM message
```

if 'count' column starts in a number greater than 0, instead of max, use range between max and min + 1

```
  SELECT ( count(*) != (max(count) - min(count) + 1) ) AS MISSING_MESSAGE FROM message
```

Comment: good solution, thanks. Lets say one day I decide to delete the first 50 messages and I know that the first message is number 51. Can we modify the query for this case?

Comment: @NoobieNoob yes, using the range between max and min, + 1, because if you only have 1 record e.g (51) the range will be 0 (51-51)  but the expected row count is 1

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of missed count's

```
SELECT a.count - 1
FROM message a LEFT JOIN message b ON b.count = a.count - 1
WHERE a.count > 1 && b.count is NULL
```